# Double Limits When Defining Improper Integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, notation, improper-integrals

In my textbook , an improper integral is defined as shown below, where $F$ is a primitive function of a function $f$.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{\ d}x\mathrel{\overset{\text{def}}{=\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}=}}\lim_{b\to+\infty}F(b)-\lim_{a\to-\infty}F(a) \tag{1}$$

Could I rewrite it in one of the following ways?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{\ d}x\mathrel{\overset{\text{def}}{=\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}=}}\lim_{a\to+\infty}\int_{-a}^af(x)\mathrm{\ d}x \tag{2}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{\ d}x\mathrel{\overset{\text{def}}{=\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}=}}\lim_{a\to-\infty}\lim_{b\to+\infty}\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{\ d}x \tag{3}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{\ d}x\mathrel{\overset{\text{def}}{=\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}=}}\lim_{b\to+\infty}\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{\ d}x \tag{4}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{\ d}x\mathrel{\overset{\text{def}}{=\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}=}}\underset{b\to+\infty}{\lim_{a\to-\infty}}\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{\ d}x \tag{5}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{\ d}x\mathrel{\overset{\text{def}}{=\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}=}}\lim_{(a,b)\to(-\infty,+\infty)}\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{\ d}x \tag{6}$$

What would be the differences between each one of these notations (talking about the limits)? Actually, are any of them even valid?

Comment: Have to be careful with repeated limits. They don't necessarily commute.

Comment: These are not necessarily Equivalent [ When Integral (1) Exists , the other Integrals may not Exist or each may Evaluate to a Different Value ] Depending on the functions $f(x)$ & $F(x)$ & the way the variables $a$ & $b$ tend to $\pm \infty$ !

Comment: (3) and (4) are the same. Did you mean to switch the limits on (4)?

Comment: Also, don't (5) and (6) mean the same thing?

Comment: @Prem - No, I think if (1) exists then the others also exist and have the same value, since $\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$. Could you give a counterexample? -- I know (1) may not exist while (2) exists; e.g. with $f(x)=x$.

Comment: @aschepler yes, changed it.

Comment: (2) has a name – it's called the *principal value* of the integral.

Comment: @mr_e_man I've seen both notations online, but don't know what is the difference. That's the reason why I asked the question.

Comment: (1) and (2) are not equivalent, since (1) may be undefined since it is possible that $\infty-\infty$ arises. Take for example $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$, then the integral over $[-a,a]$ vanishes because $f$ is odd. But $F(x)$ diverges to $\pm\infty$ for $x\to\pm\infty$ giving an undefined expression in (1).
Therefore, the existence of (2) doesn’t imply the existence of (1). On the otherhand, if (1) is defined, then it follows that (2) is correct.

Comment: [A] I wanted to type "one Integral" & wanted to change it to "Integral (N)" , though by typo , it became "Integral (1)" , @mr_e_man , [B] Either way , (1) Existence will not give all others Existence + Equivalence. I might try to Post Examples in a while.

Comment: From the Related list: [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4174052/is-the-following-definition-for-an-improper-integral-of-a-function-with-two-cr), [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687691/can-improper-integral-from-minus-infinity-to-postive-infinity-be-defined-as-doub).

Comment: @Bolzano - The only difference from (6) is that (5) excludes $a=-\infty$ exactly or $b=+\infty$ exactly. But those were excluded anyway, as $a$ and $b$ are supposed to be real numbers (which $\infty$ is not).

Comment: Your Point is valid , @mr_e_man , (5) & (6) are "Almost Equivalent" except for excluding the limiting value of $a$ & $b$ , hence when the limiting value is $\infty$ , (5) & (6) are "Entirely Equivalent" !!

Answer (score 2):

### Example 1 :

Consider $f(x)=x+c$ , where $c$ is a Constant.

When we Integrate it with (1) , we will get $[b^2/2+cb]-[a^2/2+ca]$ which is $\infty-\infty$ & (1) will not Exist , even when $c$ is Zero.

When we Integrate it with (2) , we will get $[a^2/2+ca]-[(-a)^2/2+c(-a)]=2ca$ which will not Exist when $c$ is Non-Zero , though it will Exist when $c$ is Zero , in which Case the Negative Area "cancels" the Positive Area.

With Current function , (3) & (4) are almost Equivalent to (1) , though there are other functions where these are not Equivalent.

With (5) & (6) ( which are entirely Equivalent to each other ) , we have Single limit , hence we can control the variables , eg : We can make $b=-a+c$ , ensuring that $(a,b) \to (\infty,-\infty)$ : then Integral will be $0$ , the Negative Area "cancelling" the Positive Area.
We might alternately make $b=-a^2$ , ensuring that $(a,b) \to (\infty,-\infty)$ : then Integral will tend to $-\infty$ , because we are making the Negative Area larger than the Positive Area.
In Case we make it $b=-a+c+1$ , then Integral will tend to $+\infty$ , because we are making the Positive Area larger than the Negative Area.
Let $c=0$ , then $b=-a+D/a$ ( where $D$ is a Constant ) will make the Positive Area & Negative Area "almost" Equal , except for a thin Part with Area $D$ : Overall Integral will be $D$.
We get varying values : This indicates that (5) & (6) will not Exist.

### Example 2 :

Consider $f(x)=\sin(x)$ , where Area across 1 cycle is $0$ , though the Integral will not Exist in the limit.
(1) , (3) , (4) will not Exist
(2) will be Zero.
(5) & (6) may be Zero when $b=-a+2\pi$ , thought Integral Value can vary with $b=-a+D$ , & it will not Exist when $b=-a^2$

### Example 3 :

Consider $f(x)=e^{-(x-c)^2}$ , which has Same value with all the given Integrals.

### Example 4 :

Consider $f(x)=\frac{(x-c)}{((x-c)^2+1)}$ , which has Positive Area beyond $x=c$ , though that is "cancellable" with the Negative Area.

### ADDENDUM :

(1) When taking limits with Multivariable Calculus , where we have 2 or more variables in the limit , we say that the limit Exists when we get Exact Same Value no matter which way the limit is approached.

(1A) Similarly , (5) & (6) will Exist when we get Exact Same Value no matter which way the variables tend to $\infty$ , otherwise we have to say that the Integral will not Exist.

(1B) With the limit Concept , let us say we get (3) & (4) like $a/b$ : then , Overall Integral will be $a/\infty=0$ with (3) , while it will be $-\infty/b=-\infty$ with (4) , hence Order will matter.

(2) We will have Equivalence between the Integrals when there is Positive Area all over. Equivalence will be lost when we want "cancelation" , which will require that all Possible ways to "cancel" will give that Exact Same Value.

### SUMMARY :

Each Integral [ Except (6) ] is unique here , not necessarily Equivalent , in general.

Comment: Example 2 should conclude that (5) and (6) do not exist. In addendum 1, I'm not sure what "when taking limits with Multivariable Calculus" means. You're just describing what a limit parameterized by multiple variables is.

Comment: I have added that line , @aschepler , thank you. The other Point was to show that this is the Same limit Concept , though it might look like Integration : We have to get "Same" Value in every way.

Comment: That may be true , though when (1) will not Exist , then some other Integral may Exist , @mr_e_man , which is my Example 2 here. That is enough to see that (1) is not Equivalent to (2) in general.

Comment: What are you saying with (1B)? What function has $F(b)-F(a)=a/b$ ?

Comment: Given [post1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4174052/is-the-following-definition-for-an-improper-integral-of-a-function-with-two-cr) and [post2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687691/can-improper-integral-from-minus-infinity-to-postive-infinity-be-defined-as-doub) (which @mr_e_man linked in the comment of my question – thank you for that), I struggle to understand your answer, Prem. Could you please try to elaborate even further why non of the equations from $(2)$ to $(6)$ are equivalent to $(1)$?

Comment: [[1]] It is not Exactly $a/b$ , I said "**like** $a/b$" , eg $\log(a)-\log(b)$ , @mr_e_man , It is merely Example to show that the Order matters when taking limit ( either with given function or via Integration ) [[2]] In ADDENDUM , I have already covered what you want to claim when I said "We will have Equivalence between the Integrals when there is Positive Area all over" ( which is when (1) Exists & all others will Exist too ) , though that is not Universal Equivalence.

Comment: (A) You should to work out Example 1 & Example 2 in Detail , to see what is going on , @Bolzano , then you will see which are always Equivalent & which are sometimes Equivalent. (B) In your Pointer 1 , the last line of the Accepted Answer says "I am assuming that all the limits involved are finite" while my Example covers the Case where the Individual limits are not finite too. (C) I have not yet analysed your Pointer 2 , though it seems to say something **like** $1 \implies 2$ ( that too , within some Cases ) , not $1 \iff 2$ ( that too , not Universally ) (D) It is not Universal Equivalence.

Comment: I still haven't studied about limits of multivariable functions, so started to read an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_of_more_than_one_variable) on Wikipedia about it. There they make a difference between two notations used in $(5)$ and $(6)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$I_1=\lim_{b\to+\infty}F(b)-\lim_{a\to-\infty}F(a)$$
$$I_2=\lim_{a\to+\infty}\Big(F(a)-F(-a)\Big)$$
$$I_3=\lim_{a\to-\infty}\bigg(\lim_{b\to+\infty}\Big(F(b)-F(a)\Big)\bigg)$$
$$I_4=\lim_{b\to+\infty}\bigg(\lim_{a\to-\infty}\Big(F(b)-F(a)\Big)\bigg)$$
$$I_5=\lim_{a\to-\infty\\b\to+\infty}\Big(F(b)-F(a)\Big)$$

Note that $I_1$ exists if and only if the two limits

$$L_+=\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)$$
$$L_-=\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)$$

both exist.

Supposing $I_1$ exists, it follows that all the others exist and have the same value:

$$I_2=\bigg(\lim_{a\to+\infty}F(a)\bigg)-\bigg(\lim_{-a\to-\infty}F(-a)\bigg)=L_+-L_-$$
$$I_3=\lim_{a\to-\infty}\Bigg(\bigg(\lim_{b\to+\infty}F(b)\bigg)-F(a)\Bigg)=\lim_{a\to-\infty}\bigg(L_+-F(a)\bigg)$$
$$=L_+-\bigg(\lim_{a\to-\infty}F(a)\bigg)=L_+-L_-$$
$$I_4=\lim_{b\to+\infty}\Bigg(F(b)-\bigg(\lim_{a\to-\infty}F(a)\bigg)\Bigg)=\lim_{b\to+\infty}\bigg(F(b)-L_-\bigg)$$
$$=\bigg(\lim_{b\to+\infty}F(b)\bigg)-L_-=L_+-L_-$$
$$I_5=\Bigg(\lim_{a\to-\infty\\b\to+\infty}F(b)\Bigg)-\Bigg(\lim_{a\to-\infty\\b\to+\infty}F(a)\Bigg)=L_+-L_-$$

---

It has been noted in comments that $I_2$ may exist while $I_1$ does not. For example, take $f(x)=x/(x^2+1)$, so $F(x)=\tfrac12\ln(x^2+1)$, which gives $I_2=0$ but $L_+=L_-=\infty$.

On the other hand, excluding $I_2$, all of them are equivalent.

---

Suppose $I_3$ exists:

$$I_3=\lim_{a\to-\infty}\bigg(\lim_{b\to+\infty}\Big(F(b)-F(a)\Big)\bigg)$$

In order for the outer limit to exist, the inner limit must exist for every $a$ (though we only need it for one value of $a$):

$$\lim_{b\to+\infty}\Big(F(b)-F(a)\Big)$$

Any constant can be added to a limit, so we find that $L_+$ exists:

$$L_+=\lim_{b\to+\infty}F(b)=\lim_{b\to+\infty}\Big(F(b)-F(a)\Big)+F(a)$$

Then we have

$$I_3=\lim_{a\to-\infty}\bigg(L_+-F(a)\bigg)$$

and again by adding a constant (and negating) we find that $L_-$ exists:

$$L_-=\lim_{a\to-\infty}F(a)=L_+-\lim_{a\to-\infty}\bigg(L_+-F(a)\bigg)$$

Therefore $I_1=L_+-L_-$ also exists.

By similar reasoning, $I_4$ implies $I_1$.

---

And $I_5$ implies $I_3$ and $I_4$. But we need more than those simple limit laws (e.g. "limit of sum is sum of limits"). Consider something like $\cos(a)/b$, which has a limit as $(a,b)\to(\infty,\infty)$ but no limit as only $a\to\infty$. Of course, that doesn't have the form $F(b)-F(a)$.

The definition of $I_5$ is this:

$$\forall\varepsilon>0,\;\exists D>0,\;\forall a<-D,\;\forall b>D,\;|F(b)-F(a)-I_5|<\varepsilon$$

(In words: For any neighbourhood of the point $I_5\in\mathbb R$, there is some neighbourhood of $\infty$ (that is a half-infinite interval) such that, if both $b$ and $-a$ are large enough to be in the latter neighbourhood, then $F(b)-F(a)$ is close enough to $I_5$ to be in the former neighbourhood.)

Based on that, we want to show that $L_+$ exists. We can use Cauchy's criterion to prove that it exists without knowing what it is exactly. The criterion is

$$\forall\varepsilon'>0,\;\exists D'>0,\;\forall x_1>D',\;\forall x_2>D',\;|F(x_1)-F(x_2)|<\varepsilon'$$

(In words: For any distance $\varepsilon'$, there is some neighbourhood of $\infty$ such that all points in that neighbourhood have their $F$ values close to each other, closer than $\varepsilon'$.)

So, given any $\varepsilon'>0$, we can plug in $\varepsilon=\tfrac12\varepsilon'$ to the definition of $I_5$, which will give us some $D$ with the above properties. Then it suffices to take $D'=D$. Indeed, for any $x_1>D$ and $x_2>D$,

$$|F(x_1)-F(x_2)|=\bigg|\Big(F(x_1)-F(-x_1)-I_5\Big)-\Big(F(x_2)-F(-x_1)-I_5\Big)\bigg|$$
$$\leq\Big|F(x_1)-F(-x_1)-I_5\Big|+\Big|F(x_2)-F(-x_1)-I_5\Big|$$
$$<\varepsilon+\varepsilon\quad=\varepsilon'$$

Therefore $L_+$ exists. By similar reasoning, $L_-$ exists, and thus $I_1$.

Comment: I didn't even read the answers I linked. Now I see that I've repeated their arguments.

Comment: [A] You are assuming finite limits , like my Example 3 , where all Integrals are finite & Equivalent. When one infinite limit on one side is cancelling the other infinite limit on the other side , Equivalence is lost. [B] When showing Equivalence between $I3$ & $I1$ , you are adding & subtracting certain values which you assume are finite. Proof will not work when these are not finite or do not Exist which is the Exact Case where the Equivalence is lost. [C] Equivalence means $n \implies m$ AND $m \implies n$ [D] You can check with Example (2) where $I1$ will not Exist , yet $I2$ will Exist.

Comment: All correct. [A,B] I take a limit existing to mean that it's a real number. $\infty$ is not a real number. [D] I have stated in the answer that $I_1$ may not exist while $I_2$ exists. [C,D] In case it wasn't clear, I meant that if any one of $I_1,I_3,I_4,I_5$ exists (finitely) then they all exist and are equal.